# Will I be allowed to board a two-legged flight if I do not have the required visa for the second leg of the flight?

Tags: visas, schengen, stopovers

I purchased a flight from Brazil to Spain, with stopover in Morocco. My intention is to fly to Morocco and not take the second leg to Spain. I do not need a visa to Morocco but I need a Schengen Visa to enter Spain. Will I be allowed to board the first leg (Brazil->Morocco)?

Thanks.

Comment: You could be lucky, it happens, but you should expect to be denied boarding.

Comment: You are trying to have the airline assist you in "hidden city ticketing".  That won't end well at all.

Comment: These hidden-city fares and the airlines' war on them just create problems all over the board.  They'd all go away if the gov't decreed "you cannot charge less for ABC than you charge for AB".  Or at least bless it so the airlines can't punish you...

Comment: I'm with @Harper.  If "hidden city ticketing" is a thing, it's only because the airlines allow it to be a thing in the first place by pricing unreasonably.  They get no sympathy from me on this.

Comment: @Harper "...if the gov't..." You write as if there's only one...

Comment: When you disembark in Morocco, they will tie you to a camel and drive it out into the desert.

Comment: Is it an actual "stopover" (usually meaning you're staying over 24 hours, and are expected to retrieve your checked luggage, and exit the airport after the first flight, and check-in again for the next flight), or just a stop / "layover" (where you're checked-through to the destination, luggage follows, and you're not supposed to exit the airport)?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Not a duplicate at all. This question is specifically about visa requirements.

Comment: You could just check in for the first leg and claim 'your girlfriend will meet you in Maroc with your Visa', and you plan then to check in the second leg. Or do an online checkin for only one leg. But as mentioned, you _will_ lose your return trip.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The other question is about potential issues, and visa requirements are the issue #1 there.

Answer (score 24):

No.  The airline will not give you a boarding pass for your first flight unless you have the documents you require to enter your final destination.

(Furthermore, if you tell them that you have no intention of flying to Spain, they'll cancel your ticket.)

(Furthermore, if your ticket is a round-trip ticket, when you fail to fly the Morocco-to-Spain leg, they will cancel all remaining legs of your ticket, and you'll have to buy a new ticket if you intend to return to Brazil.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not but I have boarded **domestic** flights without any attempt to verify that I was legal to fly the second leg.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65712/discussion-on-answer-by-loren-pechtel-will-i-be-allowed-to-board-a-two-legged-fl).